# How to attach a element to an iframe form?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

This is my code for an iframe

```
<iframe id='SoapExeFrame' src='' style='display:none'>
<form id='soapdatas' action='ps_dlgwnd_3.jsp' method="post">
</form>
</iframe>
```

I want to attach some form element before submitting the request to the target jsp page, so i wrote the below code

```
var oInput = SoapExeFrame.document.createElement('INPUT');
oInput.name ="webservice/webservice";
oInput.value = valueofService;
SoapExeFrame.soapdatas.appendChild(oInput);
```

but IE11 is throwing an error which points out soapdatas doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting iFrame document is different to a normal document, that's why you may be having trouble.

```
var SoapExeFrame = document.getElementById('SoapExeFrame').contentDocument || document.getElementById('SoapExeFrame').contentWindow.document;

var oInput = SoapExeFrame.createElement('input');
oInput.name ="webservice/webservice";
oInput.value = valueofservice;
    //Append to the form
SoapExeFrame.getElementById('soapdatas').appendChild(oInput);
```

I ran this in http://codepen.io, and I found that the iFrame didn't contain the form, this is the other reason you may not be able to use it as the data inside it is in the event the iFrame isn't functional in that browser (I believe), you will need to sort that first then the javascript will work.

Comment: hi , can you help me how to get the iframe functional and sort out the problem

Comment: Can you help me to get that form available

Comment: Can you give me more context, like why you don't just put the button in without javascript

Comment: iframe is done to make pseudo ajax calls this iframe is just used to collect all the data nad then submit it to servlet. Anyway I am working on another workaround. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I could be of service